Book about a boy who fights aliens by bringing TV commercials to life
I'm trying to find this book I read when I was younger (about 20years.)  It was about a boy who brings TV commercials to life to help fight an alien invasion. Super weird, but it pops back into my head every now and then.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover?  What kind of TV commercials?  I'm trying to imagine how the current crop of TV ads would fight aliens?

@DavidW - we'll be safe from the aliens as long as they suffer from erectile dysfunction and the pain of gingivitis.

I do not remember the cover but I distinctly remember there was one commercial "hero" who was an ad for insect repellent. They all had jingles or slogans that they essentially lived by. They didn't know they were commercials until partway through the book.
